# Is there a purely category-theoretic description of the total quotient ring?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The following is well-known: let $R$ denote a commutative ring and $S$ denote a submonoid. Write $S^{-1}R$ for the localization of $R$ at $S.$ Then the canonical morphism $R \rightarrow S^{-1}R$ is necessarily an epimorphism.

I'm wondering if this can be used to give a purely category-theoretic description of the total quotient ring.

> **Question.** Can the total quotient ring of $R$ be described as the terminal epimorphic extension of $R$? If not, does anyone know a definition of the total quotient ring in this flavour?

Definitions: if $R$ is a commutative ring, then by an *extension* of $R$, let us mean a commutative ring $E$ together with an injective homomorphism $R \rightarrow E$. Call this an *epimorphic extension* iff the aformentioned homomorphism is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings.

Comment: By "total quotient ring" do you mean the one obtained by taking $S$ maximal?

Comment: $S$ is taken to be the set of non-zero divisors and in the localizations these each become an @unit. (sorry, couldn't resist).

Comment: In other words, you want $Spec ( S^{-1}R ) \rightarrow Spec (R)$ to be the minimal affine subscheme of  $Spec ( R )$, but you can always pick the fraction field of a stalk. So this will not work in general.

Comment: @user40276 But the map from $R$ to the fraction field of a stalk ($= \text{Frac}(R/p)$ for a prime ideal $p$) is never injective unless $p = (0)$, in which case $R$ is a domain and the fraction field of the stalk is equal to $S^{-1}R$. Maybe you missed the injectivity condition in goblin's proposed characterization.

Comment: @goblin You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/110443/2126) where a characterization is given of those commutative rings $B$ admitting an injective epimorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to B$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You're right. I haven't really read the OP definition.